# Web Audio Streaming/Seeking (Mobile + Desktop) with Tracking

Tags: html, mobile, html5-audio, audio-streaming

It's been a long time since I've needed to build a streaming media solution for the web since there are so many good services providing basic needs. Ages ago I had done streaming deployments with Red5 and a frontend player like Flow or JW, but despite a lot of searching I haven't been able to determine what the best modern options are to achieve a simple web solution that has good native compatibility with mobile and desktop. I'm hoping someone can suggest a good open source stack that would be a good fit for what I'm trying to do:

- Mobile + Desktop Web Audio Support (with the possibility of some video at some point)
- Streaming (not live on-air streaming, but the ability to seek and listen without downloading the whole file and only buffering enough to for good quality as to not waste bandwidth)
- Track how much of a stream has been listened to (not the amount downloaded)
- Protecting streams (this should be pretty easy either using headers or URL patterns that expire the link/connection after a certain point of time by writing that logic into the server side but I wanted to mention it anyways)
- Lightweight, maybe 10 to 20 concurrent audio streams for now.

My initial thought, since my knowledge in the streaming space is dated, was to do it with RTMP, RTSP or HLS and something like JWPlayer for the frontend, depending on which protocol seemed to have the best support across the most devices. Or, if the client side support is good I could probably skip the media server and go with psuedo-streaming via the webserver. On the server side I could handle the access control to the streams and on the front end player I could use the API to keep track of the amount of seconds played and just ping that data in a ajax request to keep track of how much has actually been listened too (as opposed to downloaded/buffered).

The thing is I have a feeling that is probably an obsolete way to go about it in 2017. Even though I haven't turned up anything specific yet, I had a feeling perhaps there was a better solution out there utilizing Node and perhaps websockets to accomplish the same thing with a server and player coupled more tightly (server aware of playhead/actual amount played vs front end only) or a solution that leverages newer standards (MPEG-DASH?). Plus, in the past getting the other streaming protocols to be compatible across all devices was a pain and IIRC there is no universal HTML5 support for any given one of the older protocols across all browsers.

So what are the best current approaches to tackle something like this? Is a media server + a front end like JW or Flow still one of the better ways to go or are there better/easier ways to deploy a solution like this?